# Use jstl core as a local resource

Tags: jakarta-ee, jstl, libraries, taglib

I would like to download those libraries and import them from the computer to the application.

```javaee
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

How can I do that ?

If you want to know why, the server can't reach the Internet, so it won't get the libraries. I know how to do that with JQuery, but no answer found for the taglibs ...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I have resolved my problem.

People coming from outside can load the libraries. Only people from the server (so, no one) can't.